# Why won't it let me delete files from TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've got some files that are automatically generated and placed in a directory that's versioned using TFS.  I run this and add many files like `abc.sql` to the server.

Then I rerun my script and something's changed such that abc is obsolete.  My script deletes `abc.sql` from the local Windows folder.

When I run a `Compare` in TFS, it picks up the missing file, but when I try to choose `Delete` to remove the file from the server as well, I get this error:

```
The item $/.../abc.sql could not be found in your workspace, 
or you do not have permission to access it.
```

I **know** it's not in my workspace, and that's intentional.  So how can I delete a file locally, and tell TFS to delete from the server as well?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of just deleting the file in the file system, you should also mark it as deleted in the workspace and check the delete in afterwards.

If you already add files to source control, you can also mark them as deleted, e.g. by running [`tf delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k45zb450%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This command also removes the file from the disk. From a .NET application, you can start it by using [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I guess I could do that, but it seems like a lot more work when I think TFS should do the obvious thing and detect if a file is missing and just let you delete it using Source Code Explorer.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: removing files from TFS source control differs from just deleting it from the file system. Source control is the master repository that allows you to restore files that have been deleted locally. Therefore, you need to explicitly tell TFS that you also want to delete the file from source control, not just from the file system. Whether it is more work depends on your specific situation; from my experience, it is not too hard to implement. Do you already add the created files to source control when creating them? If not, `tf add` can do this for you. `tf checkin` does the checkin.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete the file locally, just have your script delete the file from TFS. Upon commit to source control, the file is deleted locally.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k45zb450(v=vs.100).aspx

`tf delete [/lock:(none|checkin|checkout)] [/recursive] [/login:username,[password]] itemspec`